# The norm of operator $\mathscr{L}$ on the finite-dimensional vector space $V$ equals the norm of operator restricted by some Invariant subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

The norm of linear transformation $\mathscr{L}$ on the finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$ with standard inner product equals the norm of linear transformation $\mathscr{L}$ restricted by some Invariant subspace $W$ by denote $\mathscr{L}_W$.

Definite the norm of linear transformation $\mathscr{L}$ as follows,
\begin{equation}
 \Vert \mathscr{L} \Vert \doteq \sup_{\Vert x \Vert_{2} =1} \Vert \mathscr{L} x \Vert_{2}
\end{equation}

Then my question is that what properties does Invariant subspace $W$ satisfies such that 
\begin{equation}
\Vert \mathscr{L} \Vert = \Vert \mathscr{L}_{W} \Vert
\end{equation}

Is your case a necessary and sufficient condition?

Thansk very much!

Comment: I give a concrete space $V = M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ which including all $n \times n $ matrix over $\mathbb{R}$ and $W = \{ S \in M_{n} | S^{T} = S\}$ and $\mathscr{L} (X) = AX + XA^{T} $

Comment: Take any $x$ with $\Vert x \Vert_2 =1$ such that $\Vert L \Vert = \Vert L x\Vert_2$ and let $W = {\rm span}(x, Tx, T^2 x, \dots, T^n x)$, where $n$ is chosen minimal (say) such that $(x, Tx, \dots, T^n x)$ is linearly dependent.

The necessary and sufficient condition is just that the (invariant) subspace $W$ contains some $x$ with $\Vert x \Vert = 1$ and $\Vert Lx \Vert = \Vert L \Vert$, although this is not really a nice condition.

Also, it is possible that there is no **strict** subspace $W$ with this property (take e.g. $\dim V = 1$, where $L : V \to V$).

Answer (score 2):

Let $x\in V$ be such that $\|x\|=1$.

Notice that $\|Lx\|^2=\langle x,L^*Lx\rangle\leq \|L^*Lx\|\|x\|=\|L^*Lx\|$, by cauchy-schwarz. Notice that ,$\|Lx\|^2\leq \|L^*Lx\|\leq \|L^*L\|$.

Remind that $\langle x,L^*Lx\rangle= \|L^*Lx\|$ if and only if $L^*Lx=\lambda x$.

Since $L^*L$ is self-adjoint and positive semidefinite then $\|L^*L\|$ is the biggest eigenvalue of $L^*L$  and $\|L^*Lx\|=\|L^*L\|$ if and only if $L^*Lx= \|L^*L\| x$.

Therefore,$\|Lx\|^2=\|L^*Lx\|=\|L^*L\|$ if and only if  $L^*Lx= \|L^*L\| x$.

We know that such $x\in V$ exists then $\|L\|=\sqrt{\|L^*L\|}$.

Now, let us consider $W$. Since $W$ is finite dimensional then the set $S_W=\{w, \|w\|=1, w\in W\}$ is compact. Thus, $\|L_{W}\|=max\{\|Lw\|, w\in S_W\}=\|Lw'\|$ for some $w'\in S_W$.

Therefore,   $\|L\|^2=\|L^*L\|=\|Lw'\|^2=\|L_W\|^2$ if and only if $L^*Lw'= \|L^*L\| w'$, for some $w'\in S_W$.

Finally, $\|L_{W}\|=\|L\|$ if and only if $ker(L^*L-\|L^*L\|Id)\cap W\neq \{0\}$.

Comment: It has a little blemish,but you give a afflatus which makes me to research in deep and thank you very much.